# I use Pandas mask in order to take a data from dataframe by using input dates but start date's date is not appear

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Goal is simple what I want is to get two date inputs and take some datas from a dataframe. Here is the code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

plt.rc('font', family = 'Malgun Gothic')
df = pd.read_csv('seoul.csv', encoding = 'cp949', index_col=False)
df.style.hide_index()
del df['지점']

a = input("날짜 입력 yyyy-mm-dd: ")
b = input("날짜 입력 yyyy-mm-dd: ")

df['날짜'] = pd.to_datetime(df['날짜'])
mask = (df['날짜']>a) & (df['날짜']<=b)
df2.loc[mask,['날짜','최고기온(℃)']]
```

And here is inputs and the result.

[image: Inputs_and_the_result]

How can I make the result begin from the start date that i put in?

Comment: `mask = (df['날짜']>=a) & (df['날짜']<=b)`?

Comment: oh they works! thx

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = (df['날짜']>=a) & (df['날짜']<=b)
```

yet i am an idiot